# Completely outplayed by this definite integral problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For $x$ belonging to $R$ and a continuous function $f$, let $A$=$$\int_{sin^2t}^{1+cos^2t} xf[{x(2-x)}]dx$$ and $B$=$$\int_{sin^2t}^{1+cos^2t} f[x(2-x)]dx$$ then what would be the value of $\frac{A}{B}?$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Try changing the variable $x\mapsto 2-x$ in the definition of $A$.  Note that $$1+\cos^2(t)=2-\sin^2(t)\,.$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit further.. I'm still not getting any clues

Comment: You are too quick to give up.  Well, then a further hint is to find $A+A$.

Comment: On proceeding as you said in your answer I get $A$=$$\int_{sin^2t}^{1+cos^2t} (2-x)f[{(2-x)x}]dx$$ and $B$=$$\int_{sin^2t}^{1+cos^2t} f[{(2-x)x}]dx$$ so isn't there still a difference of that term $(2-x)$ between the two?

Comment: What about the second hint?

Comment: Yeah what about it. I'm not getting what to do with it

Comment: You now have two formulae for $A$.  The second hint involves two occurrences of $A$.  This is my final hint.

Comment: Yeah but how to completely solve it? Do I subtract it from the previous one?